# Add Apple Pay Card on Xcode 7.2 iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, applepay

I'm using the iOS/iPhone6 simulator from Xcode 7.2. Following the steps on [Apple Pay Stripe integration guide](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay/web) I just can't find the `Wallet & Apple Pay` link on the settings screen. I'm already logged on a iCloud tester account. Am I missing something? I just can't find Apple Pay settings on iOS simulator.

Comment: Pretty sure you have to do this on a physical device.

Answer (score 3):

You can simulate Apple Pay from the Hardware Menu in the iOS Simulator.

For security reasons, you are not allowed to actually add credit cards or make real payments.

Answer (score 3):

The other posts are mostly right. To add a credit card you need to be on a physical device and if you're testing you should be logged into a [Apple Pay Sandbox Account](https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-pay-sandbox/).

However, you can still test just fine with the Simulator, just use the **Pay with Passcode** button and it will fetch a fake `paymentToken` from Apple.

[image]

Comment: Can we do it from India? I know Apple Pay is not supported in India. But can we simulate it? at least in a simulator?

Comment: @vinbhai4u have found any way to do it? I am from India. stuck on the same.

Comment: Nope, We had an iPhone imported from US, that worked. But Indian bought iPhones didn't had apple Pay unfortunately.

Comment: In the simulator, you can change the region in the phone settings, but if you need to add the credit card on an actual device, then that's probably not very helpful.