# Can we test Apple Pay in iPhone or iPad simulator?

Tags: ios-simulator, applepay, applepay-web

Im trying to test Apple Pay in iPhone and iPad simulator. Apple Pay is working fine in Mac laptop.

When Im trying to add a test card in wallet I'm getting below error

[image]

I have logged in with Apple Pay sandbox account and changed to UK region in that simulator.

I have tried with iPad simulator but in iPad simulator the wallet option is not showing up..

[image]

I have checked the "allowed apps" and profile settings but the Wallet option didn't shown up.. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Same happens to me on my iPhone14 simulator.

To add a credit card you need to be on a physical device and if you're testing you should be logged into a Apple Pay Sandbox Account.

I'm working on a flutter app that uses a WebView with NEXI payment gateway.
After enabling apple pay on Nexi provider, the button "Pay with apple pay" appears but you can test only the front-end behaviour because apple payment response is always empty.

[I've founded some infos here.](https://ali-akhtar.medium.com/working-with-apple-pay-27632ee23482)
and
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39777678/)