# How to use and test Wallet Transaction Shortcut in iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, wallet, sirishortcuts

The Shortcuts app offers the possibility to trigger shortcuts/intends when a wallet credit card is used and a new transaction is created.

I would like to add transaction details to one of my apps and use such a shortcut for it. Other apps do the exact same thing, so this should not be a problem.

Adding a shortcut to my app was not a big deal. However, how can this be tested on simulator?

When trying to add a new automatization in the Shortcuts app using a wallet transaction as trigger I cannot finish the setup dialog since the Next button is disabled. I assume this is because no card is configured.

When trying to add a card in Wallet I just receive that this was not successful.

I have connected the simulator to a Sandbox Apple ID account using a region which supports Apple Pay (US). Using a real account does not solve the problem.

Any idea how to get this working?

Using real transaction within a store could obviously not be the solution for debugging.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting Apple I can confirm, that it is not possible to test this functionality in Simulator. So if one would like to use this feature, one has to to do the debugging while doing real shopping...

Comment: My team are in the same boat, we will need to get hold of actual iOS devices to test a Wallet Extension.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76944386/can-we-test-apple-pay-in-iphone-or-ipad-simulator